# how to integrate push notification in android webview app

Tags: javascript, android, push-notification, android-webview

Very abstract question indeed, but still asking.

Problem
How do we integrate push notification into the android webview app created. With native apps, documentation is pretty vast and there is also tons of material on integrating push notification in webpage, which i have already done. But integrating push notification in android webview app seems to have absolutely little documentation regarding it.

What i have done
I have registered my app with firebase console and did everything as said in the documentation.
Created webview app with android studio.
added google-services.json as said in fcm in the code.

What i want to achieve
I want to send push notification from firebase console to my app users.

Appreciate if you could provide us a direction as how we go about this issue.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You are right, it is a very abstract question. Your question sais nothing what you really want to achieve. You should explain what you mean with "integrate push notification". You should also present some code. I'd be happy to help you then.

Comment: so you have an android app that shows a webpage in a webview?

Comment: Yes, i call my webpage in the webview